# react-native run-android has error, How to fix it?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I want run my first react native project, I use linux and i want run android project.
I install lastest version of android studio and install android SDK and I export PATH in shell config.
I create project with `react-native init albums` and open `albums/android` with android studio, android studio auto install gradle and it haven't error.
I create an AVD with android 4.0.3 and run it.
I want run my project with `react-native run-android`, but i get an error:

```
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
:app:checkDebugClasspath UP-TO-DATE
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:copyDebugBundledJs SKIPPED
:app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugLibraries UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:installDebug
Skipping device 'Nexus_5X_API_15(AVD) - 4.0.4' for 'app:debug': minSdkVersion [16] > deviceApiLevel [15]
:app:installDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> Failed to install on any devices.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
28 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 27 up-to-date
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

How i can fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your app is targeting 16 API level of Android and you are trying to run it in a lesser API (15). Try changing the API level in the manifest but, I think that the lesser Android API is 16 if you want to run React Native Apps.

Comment: Simpler : create another AVD with Android Studio, with API level >= 16, start that virtual device, nd run your command again, install should be ok

Comment: I change AVD to 16 API, app run but I get new error: `Could not run adb reverse: Command failed: /home/masoud/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native#requirements) page:

`Supported target operating systems are >= Android 4.1 (API 16) ...`

You are tying to build into a device with API 15. Not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the following method into your build.gradle (before the allprojects method)

   subprojects {
       project.configurations.all {
           resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
               if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                       && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                   details.useVersion "28.0.0"
               }
           }
       }
   }
2. Change your react native version to 0.57.3 in package.json
3. And be happy